# Unity Microsoft Login Not working in WebGL, but does in Windows

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl, msal

```
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using UnityEngine;
     using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
     using UnityEngine.Events;
     using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
     using System;
     using System.Threading.Tasks;
    
    public class MSALLoginScript : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject webRequestObj;
        public MyWebRequest webRequest;
    
        public string LoginUsername;
        public string LoginPassword;
    
        private const string clientId = "4c203cba-62cd-42e4-984d-d4b765c65051";
        private const string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/v2.0";
        public const string redirectUri = "http://localhost:3011/";
    
        private string[] scopes = { "User.Read" };
    
        private IPublicClientApplication publicClientApp;
        private AuthenticationResult authenticationResult;
    
        // Public property to store the user's email
        public string UserEmail;
    
        public bool LoggedIn;
    
        private void Start()
        {
            InitializeMSAL();
            LoggedIn = false;
        }
    
        void InitializeMSAL()
        {
            Debug.LogError("MSAL INITIALIZED");
            publicClientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientId)
                .WithAuthority(new System.Uri(authority))
                .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
                .Build();
        }
    
        public void RequestLogin()
        {
            Debug.LogError("TRYING TO LAUNCH LOGIN PAGE");
            List<string> scopeList = new List<string>(scopes);
    
            // Define your custom state value here
            string customState = "YourCustomStateValue";
    
            Dictionary<string, string> extraQueryParams = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "state", customState }
        };
    
            publicClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopeList)
                .WithUseEmbeddedWebView(true)
                .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)
                .ExecuteAsync()
                .ContinueWith(task =>
                {
                    if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
                    {
                        Debug.LogError($"MSAL Login failed: {task.Exception.Message}");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        authenticationResult = task.Result;
    
                    // Retrieve user's email from the account property
                    Debug.Log($"MSAL Login successful. Access Token: {authenticationResult.AccessToken}, User Email: {UserEmail}");
                        UserEmail = authenticationResult.Account.Username;
                        StaticValues.Email = UserEmail;
                        webRequest.Set_SentBy(UserEmail);
                        LoggedIn = true;
                    }
                });
    
            Debug.LogError("CODE SHOULD'VE RAN");
        }
    
    
        private async Task RequestLoginWithCustomState(string customState)
        {
            List<string> scopeList = new List<string>(scopes);
    
            Dictionary<string, string> extraQueryParams = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "state", customState }
        };
    
            await publicClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopeList)
                .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)
                .WithExtraQueryParameters(extraQueryParams)
                .ExecuteAsync();
        }
    
        public void RequestManualLogin()
        {
            Debug.LogError("TRYING TO MANUALLY LOG IN");
            List<string> scopeList = new List<string>(scopes);
    
            publicClientApp.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopeList, LoginUsername, LoginPassword)
                .ExecuteAsync()
                .ContinueWith(task =>
                {
    
                    if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
                    {
                        Debug.LogError($"MSAL Login failed: {task.Exception.Message}");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        authenticationResult = task.Result;
    
                        // Retrieve user's email from the account property
                        Debug.Log($"MSAL Login successful. Access Token: {authenticationResult.AccessToken}, User Email: {UserEmail}");
                        UserEmail = authenticationResult.Account.Username;
                        StaticValues.Email = UserEmail;
                        webRequest.Set_SentBy(UserEmail);
                        LoggedIn = true;
                    }
                });
    
            Debug.LogError("CODE SHOULDVE RAN");
        }
    
        public void SetLoginUsername(string input)
        {
            LoginUsername = input;
        }
    
        public void SetLoginPassword(string input)
        {
            LoginPassword = input;
        }
    }
    }
```

Good afternoon peeps, I've been busy with an app for a company. They want a microsoft login in their app, and want the app to be reachable by a lot of devices.

So, I thought, I will make a WebGL build.

I use Microsoft.Identity.Client to open the browser with a login tab, and then get the email after the login succeeded.

It all works fine in a windows build, but in a WebGL build just nothing happens. I tried adding error debug statements to view in a development WebGL build, and they all execute fine, which means the Microsoft code also runs.

I've also tried to use the .AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword function, which also executes I think, but does nothing.

Anybody got an idea how to fix this? I've been trying for two weeks maybe.

Thanks in advance!

I've tried:

- Switching to .NET Framework
- Using .WithUseEmbeddedView(true)
- Assembling the URL to open (Is of no use, because the login isn't even initialized)
- Using .AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword

Comment: did you allow http connections in the build options?

Comment: Where can I find that setting? I've been looking for a bit but can't find it
[EDIT]: Do you mean the "Allow downloads over http" setting? Cause if I search for it in the project settings, the player tab shows, but I can't actually find the setting there.

Comment: Aah I see, that's an option for IOS builds, I'm talking about WebGL builds.

Comment: so am I .... (as thats pretty much all i make) ...

Comment: @FlorisHooge *I've been busy with an app for a company* -> then maybe delete the value of `clientId` ?  :) Yes, even if it is harmless or useless or a test.